# Client-only Nuxt 3 D3 plugin

Tags: d3.js, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to use the D3 extension in a Nuxt 3 project and for that I created a `d3.client.js` file in the `plugins/` directory.

```
import * as d3 from "d3";
import { defineNuxtPlugin } from '#app'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
    nuxtApp.vueApp.use(d3)
})
```

However, when I try to use it gives me a 500 Internal Server Error `document is not defined`.

```
<script>
import * as d3 from "d3";

export default {
    name: "globe",
    created() {
        d3.select("#globe");
    }
}
</script>
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve it by using the `d3.select` with a Vue reference.

```
const globe = d3.select(this.$refs.globe)
```

Answer (score 1):

`d3.select()` uses `document.querySelector()` under the hood. Since you're working server side, you don't have access to `document` yet. So you'll need to mock it or to avoid using it.

You can avoid using it all together by passing an element instead of a string to `d3.select()`, as it will then create a functioning d3 selection without running `document.querySelector()`. And since every other chained `.select()` or `.selectAll()` uses `previousSelection.querySelector()`, you can just continue from there.

If you do not have access to the DOM element directly, you might want to mock `document`. [This article](https://www.gregjopa.com/2020/05/render-d3-charts-server-side) suggests using [JSDOM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom):

```js
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';

// create a new JSDOM instance for d3-selection to use
const document = new JSDOM().window.document;

d3.select(document.body)
  .append('div');
```

Comment: This didn't work as well